# Array of size 2^25

Tags: c, arrays, time, swap

I am trying to create an array of size 2^25 in c and then perform some elementary operations on it (memsweep function). The c code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#define S (8191*4096)
main()
{
                clock_t start = clock();
                unsigned i;
                volatile char large[S];
                for (i = 0; i < 10*S; i++)              
                large[(4096*i+i)%S]=1+large[i%S];

                printf("%f\n",((double)clock()-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}
```

I am able to compile it but on execution it gives segmentation fault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have that much stack space to allocate an array that big ... on Linux for instance, the stack-size is typically 8192 bytes.  You've definitely exceeded that.

The best option would be to allocate the memory on the heap using `malloc()`.  So you would write `char* large = malloc(S);`.  You can still access the array using the `[]` notation.

Optionally, if you're on Linux, you could on the commandline call `sudo ulimit -s X`, where X is some number large enough for your array to fit on the stack ... but I'd generally discourage that solution.

Answer (score 9):

That might be bigger than your stack. You can

- Make `large` global
- Use `malloc`

Comment: It IS bigger than the stack!  Try "char* larger = malloc(S)" instead of using a static buffer.

Comment: @selbie Most likely, but the size of the stack is implementation-defined so.. :)

Answer (score 4):

The array is too big to fit on your stack. Use the heap with `char *large = malloc(S)` instead.

Comment: For the sake of completeness: If you are hell bent on using an array on stack, compilers allow you to specify the stack size at compile time. I am not suggesting this approach and invite the wrath of other developers!

Comment: @hackworks that would be a bad idea because your stack is fixed size and reserved for the duration of each thread's life. You'd just be keeping around memory that you can't use, assuming the program does more than this loop.

Answer (score 3):

Large is being allocated on the stack and you are overflowing it.

Try using `char *large = malloc(S)`